# How to setup ramp up time in Jmeter for 500 concurrent users?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

We want to demonstrate that our REST API for a customer can handle 500 concurrent requests. In order to implement this, what is the best way to setup ramp up time ?

1. Is it 500 requests in 1 sec ?
2. 2500 requests in 5 seconds ?
3. Any other option ?

With first option, the app and webservers will be flooded. With second option
How should i go about setting this up ?

Appreciate any inputs on this.

Comment: Without knowing about the client and the infrastructure, it is quite hard to tell the exact numbers. Gradual ramp up is ideal for load testing. Do not inject the load immediately once the test starts. Just by the numbers above mentioned, I would say to ramp up 500 concurrent requests, have a ramp up time between 30-60 seconds with 3-9 threads.

Comment: thank u for your inputs. The load test is for REST API typically taking less than 1 sec without any load. What would be the ramp up time to simulate 500 concurrent users? Injecting all load at once is not an option. appreciate your inputs.

Comment: I have already mentioned the ramp-up in my above comment. I would say to ramp up 500 concurrent requests, have a ramp up time between 30-60 seconds with 3-9 threads. Since your REST API is taking less than a second, go for a minimum number of threads. Before the demo, execute a couple of tests. This will help you to understand your REST API behavior.

Comment: sorry, i dont understand when you say  "ramp up time between 30-60 seconds with 3-9 threads ".

Comment: Click on Thread Group and configure above settings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually performance testing has many different faces, for example:

- [Load Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing): the process of verifying whether the application under test can handle **anticipated** load, if you expect 500 users - set 500 threads under [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and configure Ramp-Up period so the load would increase **gradually**. According to [JMeter documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group):

  > Ramp-up needs to be long enough to avoid too large a work-load at the start of a test, and short enough that the last threads start running before the first ones finish (unless one wants that to happen).
  >
  > Start with **Ramp-up = number of threads** and adjust up or down as needed.

  So if you have 500 seconds ramp-up time all 500 users will be online in ~8 minutes, after that you can leave test running for some time (i.e. another 500 seconds) and then **again gradually** (500 more seconds) decrease the load to zero.

  This way you will be able to correlate increasing response time (or increasing number of errors) with the increasing load and vice versa.
- [Soak Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soak_testing): basically the same as above, but leave the test running overnight or over the weekend to see how does your application survives the prolonged load. This way you will be able to detect for example [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)
- [Stress Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing): again the same as load testing but don't limit the maximum load to 500 users, gradually increase the load until your application breaks to see how many **maximum** users it can serve. Then you might also want to gradually descrease the load to see whether it recovers when the load comes back to normal
- [Spike Testing](http://www.testingperformance.org/definitions/what-is-spike-testing): this doesn't assume any ramp-up, this way you will test how your application handles 500 users arriving **at once**

See [Why ‘Normal’ Load Testing Isn’t Enough](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-%E2%80%98normal%E2%80%99-load-testing-isn%E2%80%99t-enough) article for more detailed explanation on various performance testing types and why you need to consider all of them.

Comment: Thank u. The Rest API that we have typically gives response within 1 sec. So basically when last thread comes in the first threads wont be there. How do i make sure the server can 500 requests at the same time ?

Comment: Just set "Loop Count" on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level to `-1` and desired "Duration" under "Scheduler", this way first threads will loop through your test plan for the given duration. Check out [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected) for details.

Comment: Hello i know that this a very old post but how did you manage to run the test? I have same case where the request takes only 1 second and i have 500 users. What have you done? did you avoid the loop?